# Two Similar terms are not visible in autocomplete

Tags: ajax, taxonomy-terms

I categories and subcategories. Some sub-categories are the same (they have the same name). The user creates content (node-creation), but the autocomplete input shows only one term! But there are two identical!

Why? How does it change?

Comment: Well, before answering that, I've a question.Why do you keep identical terms? how can user recognize them if they appear twice in autocomplete dropdown?

Comment: For example "Florida" isn't only in USA. Same as many other cities/locations.

Comment: OK, got it. So are you using any Hierarchical Select module for that? or user need to select Subcategory manually?

Comment: Hierarchical select is working like "select input". I forcing user to select term manually - autocomplete.